# Unity wheel collider extra camber angle

Tags: unity, physics, vector, quaternion

I want to give the value of a camber to the wheel collider my game. When the car stops, there is no problem visually, but as the wheel rotates, the wheel makes odd rotational movements together with the value of camber.

```
foreach (var axle in axles){
    Vector3 pos;
    Quaternion rot;
    axle.wheel.GetWorldPose(out pos, out rot);
    axle.tire.position = pos;
    axle.tire.Rotate(axle.wheel.rpm / 60 * 360 * Time.deltaTime, 0, (camperValue * camperFactor));
    axle.tire.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(
         axle.tire.localEulerAngles.x,
         axle.wheel.steerAngle - axle.tire.localEulerAngles.z,
         axle.tire.localEulerAngles.z);

    axle.wheel.motorTorque = 300 * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    if (axle.index < 2)
        axle.wheel.steerAngle = 30 * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    axle.wheel.brakeTorque = 1000 * (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`axle.tire.Rotate` means that you add rotation every frame, so you're constantly adding castor value, making wheel rotate.

What you want is to set camber rotation:

```
axle.tire.rotation = rot * Quaternion.Euler(camberAxle * camber)
```

(Swap them if you got weird results.) `camberAxle` is wheel forward direction which is usually car forward direction plus wheel `steerAngle` (around `steerAxis`, which is usually `carTransform.Up`):

```
camberAxle = Quaternion.Euler(carTransform.up * steerAngle) * carTransform.forward;
```